# How should I provide DocuSign with a PDF?

Tags: api, rest, base64, docusignapi

We're using Python and the Requests library to add PDFs to DocuSign envelopes using the [`Add document`](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20Document.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%20API%20References|_____43) method of the REST API v2:

```
response = requests.put(
    '<base URL>/envelopes/<envelope ID>/documents/<next document ID>',
    files={'document': <the PDF file object>},  # <- added to the request's body
    headers=self._get_headers(
        {
            'Content-Disposition': 'document; filename="the-file.pdf";'
        }
    ),
    timeout=60
)
```

This has worked for us in most cases, except that about 1 in 100 PDFs isn't accepted via the API. When this problem occurs we tell our users to upload the PDFs directly through the DocuSign UI, which works. This prompted us (with the help of support) to look at the [`Document params`](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm) link that appears above the example request on the `Add document` page linked above. The page shows a `documentBase64` attribute, and a number of other fields. How can I supply the document in this format, with all the fields specified? Should I replace the file in my call above with `files={'document': <JSON-encoded object>}` or? I can't figure out how to add a document OTHER than the way we're currently doing it. Is there another way I'm missing?

Comment: Have you seen [DocuSign's API Walkthroughs](http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs)?  They have 9 common use cases of the REST api, each written in 6 different languages with Python being one of them.  If you look at walkthrough #4 (middle-left of the grid) you'll see how that example provides the document.  One difference I see is in the `Content-Disposition` header, setting it to `file` instead of `document`.  I'm wondering if that has anything to do with your occasional error?

Comment: @Ergin - thanks, I did see those, but they're missing the "Add Document" workflow. IIRC, the DocuSign integration development director told me that I needed to provide `<whatever name I'm calling the attachment>` in the `Content-Disposition` header, which in my case is just `"document"`. It seems unlikely that naming the attachment `"document"` would cause an error a small fraction of the time.

Comment: Oh ok I was mis-understanding the first parameter of the Content-Disposition header, didn't realize that was just the name of the attachment.  Hmm so are there any differences between the docs that they have trouble uploading through the api and the other 99 that seem to work?  Anything different about the byte encoding or security settings on those PDFs?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there are now two different ways to add a document to a Draft Envelope with the REST API:

1. Use a multi-part request, where the first part contains the JSON body and each subsequent part contains a document's bytes -- in ***un-encoded format***.  An example of this approach is shown on pages 136-137 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf).
2. Use a normal request (i.e., not multi-part request), and supply document bytes ***in base64-encoded format*** as the value of the **documentBase64** property for each **document** object in the Request.   (This looks to be new as of the recent December 2013 API release/update.)

Based on the info you've included in your question, I suspect you're currently using approach #1.  As described above, the main difference between the two approaches is the general structure of the request, and ALSO -- approach #1 expects document bytes to be un-encoded, while approach #2 expects document bytes to be base64-encoded.  I suspect your issue has to do with encoding of files.  i.e., if you're using approach #1 and any of the files are encoded, you'll likely have issues.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on Approach 2?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tutorial. But it's very simple really -- you just need to generate a base64-encoded byte stream of the document, then put this string in the request as the value of the documentBase64 property.  Search the REST API guide (https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf) for "documentBase64" -- on p112 it shows this property is a peer property of "name" and "documentId" in the document object of a request.  "documents": [{ 
 "documentId":"NUMBER", 
 "name":"STRING", 
 "documentBase64":"BASE_64_ENCODED_BYTE_STREAM"
}]

Comment: Thanks. Got it working same day, forgot to update here. I achieved it exactly the same way you mentioned.

Comment: Glad to hear that! If you get a chance, can you please mark this as an accepted answer (so that others may benefit from this information in the future)?  Thanks!